# Removing same event from listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, observer-pattern

I have a `myDiv.mousedown`, `window.mousemove`, and `window.mouseup` event. I'm trying to organize my code, and have it clean. So I created a `function` and returned the 3 event handlers.
The `mousedown` event adds a `mousemove` event, and the `mouseup` event removes the `mousemove` event.

Since I need to pass the exact same object to `removeEventListener()` as the one I used with `addEventListener()`, I have to create a variable for each event handler.

This doesn't seem to be organized and clean. Does this follow common practice? If not what is the 'correct', organized and clean code to perform that?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var VeryUsefullClass = (function() {

  function VeryUsefullClass(parentElem, options) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.index = 0;

    _this.mouseDownHandler = _this.mouseHandler().mouseDown;
    _this.mouseMoveHandler = _this.mouseHandler().mouseMove;
    _this.mouseUpHandler = _this.mouseHandler().mouseUp;

    myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', _this.mouseDownHandler);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', _this.mouseUpHandler);
  }

  VeryUsefullClass.prototype.mouseHandler = function() {
    var _this = this;
    var obj = {
      mouseDown: function(e) {
        console.log('mouseDown');
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', _this.mouseMoveHandler);
      },
      mouseMove: function(e) {
        myDiv.innerHTML = 'mouseMove ' + _this.index++;
      },
      mouseUp: function(e) {
        console.log('mouseUp');
        _this.index = 0;
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', _this.mouseMoveHandler);
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }

  return VeryUsefullClass;
})();

console.clear();

var hello = new VeryUsefullClass();
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: No `class`? Not up on the es6 yet?

Comment: Also you do not have any dependency injection. `myDiv` is global?

Comment: @Neal No, I'm not using es6 yet. In the code above `myDiv` is global, but not in my actual project.

Comment: See my answer using dependency injection (with es6) It _can_ be modified (easily) to use es5 if you want.

Comment: *In the code above myDiv is global, but not in my actual project* - this is why we ask for **actual, *real code***. There's little use in putting up your code for review if the advice you're getting isn't about your actual/real code. Not to mention the effort reviewers typically put in their answers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You're right. Thanks! I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3):

- Consider using **dependency injection**

  - What that means is "injecting" what you want to manipulate into your class (instead of relying on "global" variable), for example:

    ```
    let a = 42;
    function manipulateA () {
        return a = a + 24;
    }
    console.log(manipulateA(), a); // 66, 66
    ```

    versus:

    ```
    let a = 42;
    function manipulate (a) {
        return a = a + 24;
    }
    console.log(manipulate(a), a); // 66, 42
    ```

    This allows for much easier to test code, and you know *exactly* what will happen with everything instead of relying on something to magically happen in the global scope.

Consider this instead (using es6 and **dependency injection**):

```js
class MoveOver {
  // dependency injection
  constructor ({element = document.body}) {
    this.element = element;
    this.index = 0;
  }
  
  startListening () {
    const mouseMove = () => {
      this.element.textContent = `mouseMove_${this.index++}`;
    }
    this.element.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
      console.log('mouseDown');
      this.element.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      console.log('mouseUp');
      this.element.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    }, false);
  }
}

const move1 = new MoveOver({element: document.getElementById('mouse')});
const move2 = new MoveOver({element: document.getElementById('mouse2')});

move1.startListening();
move2.startListening();
```

```css
.cover {
  height: 200px; width: 200px;
  border: red solid 1px;
  float: left; margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse" class="cover"></div>
<div id="mouse2" class="cover"></div>
```

In the above example we are able to add the **same** events to two (2) different elements, but yet still yield the same results for both

Comment: Thanks for the **detailed** and **explained** answer! Isn't it more efficient to call a named function to an event listener, or does it not make a difference?

Comment: What do you mean @Jessica ?

Comment: Meaning something like this: `element.addEventListener('click', namedFunction); function namedFunction(e) {...}`

Comment: Sorry, can you make a fiddle or something? it is hard to convey meaning in code in a comment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2syuevz3/

Comment: That way you can remove the event explicitly. You need the original function.

Comment: So I should do it the second way, only if I plan on removing the event?

Comment: Since I want to add and remove the events, I returned two functions, (`add`, and `remove`) Does this look good? https://jsfiddle.net/sh12cxur/ (Let me know if that should be a new question.)